# Auto logout with JavaScript code in .NET 6 Blazor Server Project is not working

Tags: blazor

I am creating a project in **.NET 6 Blazor Server** side. I want to implement an auto logout feature if the system remains idle for  a certain amount of time. For authentication I have implemented **asp.net core Identity**. Here is my **Logout page**:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@functions {
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript code for auto logout:

```
function initializeInactivityTimer(dotnetHelper, miliseconds) {
    var timer;

    //the timer will be reset whenever the user clicks the mouse or presses the keyboard
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(logout, miliseconds); //600,000 milliseconds = 10 minuts
    }

    function logout() {
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync("Logout");
    }
}
```

Logout function and JavaScript calling is in **MainLayout** Page. Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainLayout
{
    [Inject] public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }   
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var time = 10000;
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeInactivityTimer", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), time);
        }
    }


    [JSInvokable]
    public Task Logout()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Logout");         
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If my system is idle for 10 miliseconds then the JavaScript code executes to redirect to the logout page. The code executes fine but it could not logout the system. Instead it showing the page not found problem. See the below image:

[image]

Here is my **App.razor** file code:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>

        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                        <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                    </LayoutView>
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And here is the location of my **Logout** page:

[image]

**Can anyone let me know how to solve the problem. How to redirect to logout page from JavaScript code?**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because you do not have the Logout.cshtml code in your question but it looks like you do not have a route defined for this page.

You would need to define the route using the @page directive.

E.g.

`@page "/Identity/Account/Logout"`

See [ASP.NET Core Blazor routing and navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for all the details on Blazor routing and navigation.